# XML and Django problems (unicode related?)

Tags: python, xml, django, unicode

I made this app that is supposed to give an xml document with 5 items. My view sends a dictionary 'rsscontent' with these five items to the file rss.xml:

```
    #views.py
return render_to_response("rss.xml", {"rsscontent":rsscontent})
```

Then the rss.xml file looks like this:

```
#rss.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="0.92">
<channel>
{% for key, value in rsscontent.items %}<item>
        <title>{{value|safe}}</title>
        <description>{{value|safe}}</description>
        <link>{{key|safe}}</link>
    </item>             
{% endfor %}
</channel>
</rss>
```

It generates an output, however the page is acting weird. The output has [u''] in it like this:

```
<title>[u'Apple iPod touch 8 GB (4th Generation) NEWEST MODEL']</title>
<description>[u'Apple iPod touch 8 GB (4th Generation) NEWEST MODEL']</description>
```

**How can I remove this?** and make sure it is normal text?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/syndication/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `|safe` filter. Additionally, it looks like your object values are lists, so you'll need to get the first element of those, rather than just printing the items themselves.

You want to modify your input `rsscontent` variable to look like this:

```
{'item1':'itemtext',
 'item2':'item2text',
  etc.
}
```

rather than your current that probably has:

```
{'item1':['itemtext',],
'item2':['item2text',],
 etc.
}
```

If you can't do that, you need to modify your template value outputs to look like this:

```
    <title>{{ value.0 }}</title>
```

This gets the first item in the list, rather than printing the list itself.

Comment: Thanks Paul! I can't lose the |safe because I will get another problem, however, the value.0 method worked for me. I couldn't figure out why this is a listobject, so I used that method, thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help! Be very careful with `|safe`, it's a very good way to make your site insecure.